# Grails Domain Tables Not Created

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I deleted the tables from the database manually due to the below issue. I have 11 domains. When I restart the Grails app, only 5 tables are created in the database.
How can I force the tables creation?

```
Hibernate: drop table if exists app
| Error 2015-01-29 20:34:01,865 [Thread-8] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop table if exists app
| Error 2015-01-29 20:34:01,865 [Thread-8] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
Hibernate: drop table if exists app_features
Hibernate: drop table if exists client
| Error 2015-01-29 20:34:01,875 [Thread-8] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop table if exists client
| Error 2015-01-29 20:34:01,875 [Thread-8] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
Hibernate: drop table if exists menu_component
| Error 2015-01-29 20:34:01,887 [Thread-8] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: drop table if exists menu_component
| Error 2015-01-29 20:34:01,888 [Thread-8] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Comment: What's the value of `dbCreate` for your data source? (You can find it in `dataSource.groovy` file).

Comment: Please post your domain class.

Comment: I use  dbCreate = "create-drop" for the development environment.
How can I order of which table to be dropped first?